# SparseArray Iterate & Remove in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a result from the queue, process it and remove it after. But I got Java exception in the case access null key, see below

```
int key = 0;
int size = mQueue.size();
for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    key = mQueue.keyAt(i);
    result = mQueue.get(key);
    // process(result);
    mQueue.remove(result.id);
}
```

---

```
>>From Queue-->{  
1=Result[id=1,type-1,data],  
5=Result[id=5,type=40,data2],  
6=Result[id=6,type=2,data3]}
```

---

```
>>From Loop-->  
i=1, key=1  
i=2, key=6<--- was expecting key= 5  
i=3, key=6<--- JE here, since mQueue.get(6) =null because removed from i=2
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over it backwards

```
for (int i = mQueue.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int key = mQueue.keyAt(i);
        Object result = mQueue.get(key);
        process(result);
        mQueue.remove(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call mQueue.remove in your loop, you are changing the size of mQueue which messes things up.

If you used a ArrayList or HashMap instead, you could use an iterator and use iterator.remove() to remove the last object returned by next from the collection.

Alternatively if you really need to use a SparseArray, you could record the objects to be removed, and do the remove in a new loop.

```
int key = 0;
int size = mQueue.size();

// Assuming your result.id field is an Integer
ArrayList<Integer> forRemoval = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    key = mQueue.keyAt(i);
    result = mQueue.get(key);
    forRemoval.add(result.id);
}

for (int i = 0; i < forRemoval.size; i++) {
    mQueue.remove(forRemoval.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove from `mQueue` while processing the `Result`s. Just mark their indices for removal and delete them once the loop is finished. The point is to not let the `SparseArray` indices to change while iterating over it.

```
int key = 0;
int size = mQueue.size();
List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    key = mQueue.keyAt(i);
    result = mQueue.get(key);
    // process(result);
    toRemove.add(result.id);
}

for (Integer id: toRemove) {
    mQueue.remove(result.id);
}
```